# Insert linked picture next to text without line break-causing placeholder

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, markdown

On a Jekyll markdown post, I want to insert a picture *(in below picture: red box)* right next to a div *(blue)*. In the below picture, the position of the red box is perfect. **Important:** The picture is linked to some text content in the div *(here: "Text of red box")*. But the way I do this, the box creates a placeholder in the blue div and causes early line breaks. **How can I let the red box float next to the div at the height of the anchor in the text without creating the empty space in the div?**

[image]

Here is the code:

```
The grapefruit (Citrus × paradisi) is a 
<span class="sidenote">
      <cite class="quelle"></cite>
      <span>Text of red box</span>
</span>
subtropical citrus tree known for its sour to semi-sweet fruit. Grapefruit is a hybrid originating in Barbados as an accidental cross between two.
The grapefruit (Citrus × paradisi) is a subtropical citrus tree known for its sour to semi-sweet fruit. The grapefruit (Citrus × paradisi) is a subtropical citrus tree known for its sour to semi-sweet fruit.
```

And the css:

```
.icon-source:before, .sidenote > cite.quelle:before {
    background-size: 45px 45px;
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
    right: -45px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    padding-top: -15px;
    width: 45px; 
    height: 45px;
    content:"";
}
```

Comment: use float:right to img

Comment: I use float:right for the cite part. If I use float:right for the sidenote span, the text "Text of red box" also floats and that's not what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, `margin-right: -90px;` pushes the placeholder out of the div:

```
.icon-source:before, .sidenote > cite.quelle:before {
    background-size: 45px 45px;
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
    right: -45px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    padding-top: -15px;
    width: 45px; 
    height: 45px;
    margin-right: -90px;
    content:"";
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use that code: I used `float:right` to do this
[code](https://jsfiddle.net/MaciejWojcik/9jmwLtr1/1/)

Comment: I use float:right for the cite part. If I use float:right for the sidenote span, the text "Text of red box" also floats and that's not what I want.

Comment: Yes, I can see your code. In your current example the red box still remains in the div.

Answer (score 0):

Try to place the image in the div. 
Set the div to poasition: relative;
Set the img to position: absolute; right: -x px

Maybe that helps...

Answer (score 0):

Change position to `position: absolute;`

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/andrey3diq/5m3dL721/)